# How to keep the recipient address editable in Thunderbird 78.4.2?

Tags: email, thunderbird, usability

The recipients are now visualized like blocks and prevents the user to move the cursor in the string. It looks very similar to the way MS Outlook shows the recipients.

[image: TO: superuser@example.com]

How to keep the recipient address editable in Thunderbird 78.4.2?

Answer (score 1):

Please see the [addressing support article](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/addressing-email).

Comment: Thank you for the link. It describes the new address format, which imitates the annoying design of Outlook. But there is no solution how to fix it. I hope there is a config setting or a patch to get the old scheme.